# Is there a shortest path algorithm with a little twist

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have a pretty general question about algorithms:
Is there a shortest path algorithm in a graph (directed or undirected) with the following twist: each added node in the path is influenced by ALL of the other already existing nodes, and that "influence" (which is in other words - the weight of the edge between the two verteces, which is only created for that single purpose) is added to the path total weight?
Thanks in advance!

Edit: another attemp to explain: let's say I want to find the shortest path from A to Z, where in between there all kind of other nodes. The thing is, If im looking into the path that starts from A and then B, and I try to calculate the total distance from A to C, the distance is actually: distance(C) = weight(A, B) + weight(B,C) + weight(A, C), even though there isn't a direct edge between A and C, and its calculated just for that purpose.

Edit2: Another explanation: lets say we have: A, B1, B2, C1, C2, D. with verteces: (A, B1)=1, (A, B2)=2, (B1, C1)=1, (B2, C2)=2, (C1, D)=1, (C2, D)=2. (right to the equal sign is the edge weight). Shortest path from A to D is of course (A->B1->C1->D), but now lets add my bizzare demand: each node added to the path is adding his weight to all other nodes in the current path, so the total distance of the following is actually: 1+1+1+ w(A->C1) +w(A->D)+ w(B1->D). those weight can be known, but can't be used for the path itself (the A, B1, C1, D). one of those could effect the algorithms wanted result.

Comment: I think youre going to have to explain a little more...

Comment: I'll try: let's say I want to find the shortest path from A to Z, where in between there all kind of other nodes. The thing is, If im looking into the path that starts from A and then B, and I try to calculate the total distance from A to C, the distance is actually: distance(C) = weight(A, C) + weight(A, B), even though there isn't a direct edge between A and C, and its calculated just for that purpose.

Comment: Aside: you should probably add all your extra stuff as edits to your original question, it helps for readability. Also, this question may do a little better in [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) since it has to do with graph theory.

Comment: Shouldn't it also add weight(B,C)? And don't listen to R Nar about Mathematics SE, this is clearly an algorithm question.

Comment: you're correct, it should - I edited the original post with your correction.

Comment: and how would you calculate the weight(A,C)? is there a specific formula for it?

Comment: lets say there's a function who can calculate the weight between each given verteces.

Comment: did you try dijkstra? if so, what property of your graph problem was giving you problems? e.g. positive weights only, is the distance A-D including weight(A,C) or not?

Comment: The problem is still very unclear to me, could you include a complete example with more than 3 nodes. Maybe it would help us understand if you explain what is the real life problem you are trying to express as a shortest path problem.

Comment: I think I see why you wouldnt be able to use dijkstra's, because, say, distance(D) [assuming a path of a-b-c-d] = weight(A,B)+(B,C)+(C,D)+weight(A,D) but does NOT include weight(A,C) right?

Comment: the problem with the "BIG 3" known shortest-path algorithms is that they can't handle my new demand as it's a little hard to explain why without a demonstration, but trust me on that - they just don't.

Comment: Do you mean to say that your network will get frequently modified and you want to update the shortest path with minimal running time using existing cached info(what you terming as influence)?

Comment: lets say we have: A, B1, B2, C1, C2, D. with verteces: (A, B1)=1, (A, B2)=2, (B1, C1)=1, (B2, C2)=2, (C1, D)=1, (C2, D)=2. (right to the equal sign is the edge weight). Shortest path from A to D is of course (A->B1->C1->D), but now lets add my bizzare demand: each node added to the path is adding his weight to all other nodes in the current path, so the total distance of the following is actually: 1+1+1+ w(A->C1) +w(A->D)+ w(B1->D). those weight can be known, but can't be used for the path itself (the A, B1, C1, D). one of those could effect the algorithms wanted result.

Comment: so what you're saying is: your problem breaks one of the assumptions in the *standard* shortest path algorithms, namely that the shortest path from A to I might not be part of any shortest path A to Z via I. is this correct?

Comment: I still cannot understand you example. What does c = w(A->B) mean? Is it different from (U, V)=c in your notations? Why are you adding specifically w(A->C1), w(A->C) and w(B1->D)? Could you write clear mathematical definition of your problem?

Comment: Ok, let's try to make it clear. Given a path *V0*, *V1*, *V2*, ..., *Vk*, the value of the goal function for it is: sum of weight(*Vi*, *Vj*) over all *0 <= i < j <= k*. You need to find a path with minimal value of the goal function. Is it right?

Comment: I don't see why the solution would be different than that generated by e.g. Dijkstra. You'd need to give a fully specified example that shows why a path generated by Dijkstra would be sub-optimal. You also don't specify what the cost of those extra "virtual" edges are (like w(A->C1)). Are they based on the cost of real edges? Arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description (without further specifying `weight(I, J)`) is breaking one of the assumptions in the standard shortest path algorithms, namely that the shortest path from A to I might not be part of any shortest path A to Z via I.

```
A -> B(2), C(1)
B -> D(2)
C -> D(1)
D -> E(2)
with non-edge costs weight(I, J) := 0, except weight(C, E) := 100
```

The shortest path from A to D is A, C, D with cost 2=1+1, while the path A, B, D has cost 4=2+2. Even so the path A, C, D, E is more expensive than A, B, D, E because of `weight(C, E)`.

In this case you're left with computing all possible paths from the start to the end node in your network, since the latest most expensive seeming path might still be cheaper when reaching the end node because of some `weight(X, <end>)`: for each node, compute the cost of all incoming paths (from the start node) until you've computed all paths, then select the cheapest one at the end node. This algorithm assumes `weight(I,J) >= 0` or that the input is a DAG.